# Can I use the R approx() function to return a different value then what is being interpolated?

Tags: r, function, approximation, interpolation

So basically I have a large data frame to two columns, one time column and one size column. I then have another data frame with just one time column. I want to interpolate the times from the data frame with just times into the other data frame, and I then want to return the sizes corresponding to the time that was just interpolated.

Example:

Table 1:

```
Time
2
4
```

Table 2:

```
Time   Size
1      40
3      50
5      30
```

I basically want to interpolate the "2" from table 1 in between the "1" and "3" in table two, and return the sizes "40" and "50"

How do I do this using the approx function?

Comment: Please show the intended output. I am not sure if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I want to return 40 and 50, like in a list...

Comment: try specifying `method = "constant"`, just a guess

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
> Table1 <- data.frame(Time = c(2, 4))
> Table2 <- data.frame(Time = c(1, 3, 5), size = c(40, 50, 30))
> approx(Table2$Time, Table2$size, xout = Table1$Time, method = "constant")
$x
[1] 2 4

$y
[1] 40 50
```

ADDED. This can also be done using the zoo package like this:

```
> library(zoo)
> z2 <- read.zoo(Table2, FUN = identity)
> na.approx(z2, xout = Table1$Time, method = "constant")
 2  4 
40 50
```

In the future please write out your input data in R so it can simply be copied and pasted into a running R session as we have done above.

Comment: thanks! I do have one question tho, where in the function do you specify to return the size values before and after the interpolated time? Like where do you tell it to return 40 and 50?

Comment: `approx` always returns both the `x` and the `y`. See Value section of `?approx`.

Comment: What does before and after refer to?

Comment: Like why is it returning 40 and 50 but not 30?

Comment: 30's time is 5 which does not carry forward to any value in xout.